# Как называется свойство, которое прописывается в хроме через -- для смены параметров?

Tags: google-chrome, cross-origin

Как называется свойство, которое записывается в хроме через `--` для изменения некоторых параметров? Мне нужно отключить проверку безопасности в хроме.

Эти параметры записываются в ярлыке через два тире `--`. Вроде их называют ключами. Я ищу тот, что отключает безопасность. Мне просто нужно сделать крос доменный запрос, который без отключения данного параметра не проходит. Кто-то вроде говорил о таком ключе, а вот найти не могу...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запустите Chrome с ключом

```
--disable-web-security
```

Именно он отвечает за искомое вам поведение.

Рекомендую обратить внимание на ответы на англоязычном Stack Overflow:
[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)